# Why isnt my .htaccess image hot-linking block not working?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hotlinking

I have tried several things to BLOCK images that are hosted on my site in a particular website/forum, and redirect to a different image of choice.

The only results I seem to get are:

- images blocked on ALL site
- images re-directed to correct re-direct image on 3rd party site..... but -ALSO- on my domain too?

I have included my FULL .htaccess (as I have a handful of other entries in there for re-directing to SSL, and well as a sub-domain used for developing a new site) as I'm un-sure if any previous entries might be messing things up?  (although I dont think so) :)

```
RewriteEngine On

#SSL Stuff
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www. mydomain.net/$1 [R=301]

#SSL Stuff
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www. mydomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

#new dev site
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging.mydomain\.net$ [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://staging.mydomain.net/$1 [R=301,L] 


# ---- [do not touch above] ----


#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http(s)://(www\.)?mydomain\.net(/)?.*$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)://(www\.)?3rd-party-hot-linker.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ http://www.some-other-domain/image.jpg [R,NC]
```

I have attempted to use the above.. as well as some variants:

```
#RewriteCond  %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http(s)://(www\.)?mydomain\.net(/)?.*$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)://(www\.)?3rd-party-hot-linker.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ http://www.some-other-domain/image.jpg [R,NC]



RewriteCond  %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http(s)://(www\.)?mydomain\.net(/)?.*$  [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)://(www\.)?3rd-party-hot-linker.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ http://www.some-other-domain/image.jpg [R,NC]



#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.net(/)?.*$  [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mydomain\.net(/)?.*$  [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?3rd-party-hot-linker.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://(www\.)?3rd-party-hot-linker.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
```

And I just cant NOT seem to get the results I am looking for!!??   I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong?   Fighting with my browser cache? or what..

Basically ANY image requests from that 3rd party forum, that have links to images hosted on mydomain.. I want to re-direct to a different image.  (thats it!)..

I dont want it to affect MY domain/site and using its images.. an no matter I have tried, I keep getting mixed results on my site.. and never the redirect image on the 3rd party site!?

- I was even see some images on mydomain being replaced..and -some- not?  (even though all were .jpg and located in same directory on mydomain?)

Completely lost here....?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please confirm if you want to block requests from `rd-party-hot-linker.com` here?

Comment: Block?  I guess technically I want to redirect ALL image type requests to a different image, like my attempt here:

RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ http://www.some-other-domain/image.jpg [R,NC]

Comment: from, `I have tried several things to BLOCK images that are hosted on my site in a particular website/forum, and redirect to a different image of choice.` I thought you are trying to block something no issues. So basically you want to rewrite any image type apart from `.jpg` to jpg in backend, Am I right here?

Comment: If a request comes from '3rd-party-hot-linker.com' for any image type (gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)..  I want to redirect to a specific .jpg image.

Comment: Please understand that `HTTP_REFERER` based rules are inherently very weak because `HTTP_REFERER` can be easily faked.

Comment: thank you, but for this scenario it should be faked, it a legit forum. I just no longer what my images that are posted there to display, but instead show a different image (the same one)

Comment: @anubhava  is there a way to check this out then?  How can I stumble into them getting the redirected image served up? (which is desired) but then also some how screw it up on my site too then?

Comment: In your first code comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)://(www\.)?3rd-party-hot-linker.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]` line and retest

Comment: @anubhava 

I now have this:
I now have this:

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http(s)://(www\.)?mydomain\.net(/)?.*$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ http://www.some-domain.com/some_image.jpg [R,NC]

Results:
Does the correct redirect on the 3rd party hotlinker site - good

However it Also redirects roughly half of the images on my domain, and others do not LOAD at all?

Shows redicted image (on MY domain): http:// mydomain.net/misc/etchingTools-002_small.jpg" - not good

Shows NO image at all = http:// mydomain.net/misc/etchingTools-001_small.jpg

Why?

Comment: Try: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mydomain\.net [NC]`

Comment: should 'mydomain' include the fully qualified url? or just mydomain  (no www or https.etc)

Comment: same results..   3rd party is redirecting to correct image....  BUT.. my domain is doing it as well (still half being re-directed and half not loading at all)

Comment: @anubhava when I right click on the image that -did not load- (left a blank/image placeholder) and then select reload image.. it then loads and shows the redirected image..  so I guess we can ignore the non-loading images portion..  but why does it even affect my site/domain at all??  The ONLY time it seems to work by blocking/displaying the redirect image on the 3rd party site.. is when it effects my site too? :(

Comment: @anubhava how can I check into this more?  How can I check to see if the site that is linking to my hosted image is even sending a referrer header?  Is there other ways to trap/check for this hot-linking to my images?

Comment: My suggested code is correct, that is being used on many sites to prevent hot linking. You can search Google and you will find similar rules. To test I suggest to use command line `curl` and pass different values of `HTTP_REFERER` in header.

Comment: _“How can I check to see if the site that is linking to my hosted image is even sending a referrer header?”_ - the browser sends the referrer, not the site. The site can tell the browser that it should send a shortened referrer, or no referrer at all though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Comment: In Dev Tools in Firefox, I see no Referrer being sent, but I see this: Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

In Chrome,. I do see a Referrer being sent.   What I am not understanding is how it only works IF I am also blocking my own images from my own site as well?  (and never JUST targeting the 3rd party site..nothing works as the forum still shows my hosted images?)